# ruby, sinatra whenever json.parse and input Datamapper

Tags: ruby, cron, sinatra, datamapper, whenever

I want use whenever and every 5 min (ex)0,5,10,15,20 ... 55) json parse site and input my database..

and instantly processing script...

config/schedule.rb

```
every '0,5,10,15,20,25,30,35,40,45,50,55 * * * *' do
 rake "do_something"
end
```

Rakefile

```
task :do_something do
        <%a = JSON.parse( open("http://named.com/page/ladder/ajax/result.php").read )%>
         <% b=a['times'] %>

        <% c=a['start_point'] %> 

        <% if c == 'first' %>
        <% c='left' %>
        <% else %>
        <% c= 'right' %>
        <% end %>

        <% d=a['ladder_type'] %>

        <% if d == 'type1' %>
        <% d='3' %>
        <% else %>
        <% d= '4' %>
        <% end %>

        <% e=a['answer'] %>
        <% if e == 'EVEN' %>
        <% e='2' %>
            <% else %>
            <% e= '1' %>
            <% end %>

=begin

I want input this result in db.
=end


    end
```

and this is schedule script.

a.rb

```
class Ladder

  include DataMapper::Resource

  property :id, Serial

  property :ladder_type, String 

  property :start_point, String 
  property :times, String 

end

class User

  include DataMapper::Resource

  property :id, Serial

  property :email, String 
  property :password, String 

  property :ladder_type, String 

  property :start_point, String 
  property :times, String 

end
```

i want input database..

ex) whenever parse and input my database and instantly processing this script.

```
if u.times == l.times
puts "good"
else
puts "lose"
end
```

Comment: You swapped the file names, the first is the config/schedule.rb, the second is the rake file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your rake task is fine, configure whenever to call it every fifth minute using:

```
every '*/5 * * * *' do
  rake "do_something"
end
```

But don't forget to run the `whenever` command on your server to update the crontab file which is responsible for time scheduled jobs. You have to do this from your application working directory, read the README / doc: https://github.com/javan/whenever